# What is a Unified Data Visualization Engine?

Tags: data-visualization

How to understand this name. Is it a tool to visualize all types of data or Unifying data and visualization?

Answer (score 0):

Data visualization is truly multi-layered multi-disciplinary area. Unified Data Visualization Engine would have to be able to:

- connect to multiple data sources
- understand various data formats
- store data in appropriate places
- work with tools for analyzing data
- send data to multiple visualization libraries
- function in variety of hardware/software configurations

Something similar to the following diagram: (this diagram is about data visualization from designer point of view) (you can make your own diagram like this to suit your needs better)

[image]